# Adding GLFW to Qt via qmake

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I am using Qt 5.15.2 and Win10 64-bit

I have just downloaded the GLFW source package from the original site, not the pre-compiled binaries. I do not know how to compile it with Qt.  Then I would like to use it in Qt.

I know that there are pre-compiled binaries but those can use only in Visual Studio.

I know that there is an integrated QtOpenGL to Qt but I would like to use the "original" OpenGL.

Edit:

I downloaded the 64-bit GLFW package.

The files location `C:/LIBS/glfw`, folder contain the following files: glfw3.dll, glfw3dll.a, libglfw3.a, glfw3.h

.pro file

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

LIBS += -LC:/LIBS/glfw/ -lglfw3

INCLUDEPATH += C:/LIBS/glfw
DEPENDPATH += C:/LIBS/glfw
```

Comment: Note that `glfw` has nothing to do with `Qt`.  To build and install it you need to follow the [appropriate instructions](https://github.com/glfw/glfw#user-content-compiling-glfw).

Comment: @G.M.  I included the glfw3.h, and I added the external library with include path and include file, from the lib-mingw folder. I copied an example code from the original site, but when I try to run the code, i get undefined reference, like `context.c:-1: error: undefined reference to `__imp_glGetIntegerv'`

Comment: @G.M. I have updated the question, I added the .pro file source code.

Comment: You need to link with the `OpenGL` library as well.

Comment: @G.M. There are 3 files in lib-mingw, where can I find the opengl lib file??

Comment: @taiwan12 It's a library that comes with mingw, and you don't need to manually find it. Just provide its name, and the linker should find it (`-lgl`).

Comment: .pro file `LIBS += -LC:/LIBS/glfw/ -lglfw3           LIBS += -lgl`     and my include `#include <GL/gl.h>     #include <glfw3.h>`  but I get an error: `cannot find -lgl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to compile the GLFW source package. The precompiled binary package contains binaries for both Visual Studio ***and*** MinGW.

You have to link the OpenGL binary, so your `LIBS` line in the `.pro` file should be:

```
LIBS += -LC:/LIBS/glfw/ -lglfw3 -lopengl32
```

And you may also have to append `-lglu32` and/or `-lgdi32` if you still get some additional link errors.